# How can I check if a dialog is a group? (telethon)

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

How could I check if the dialog is a group?

I want to make a For Loop which iterate through all dialogs and only executes a command if the dialog is a group, but I don't know how to check that.

Comment: please read [https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

`dialog.is_group`

You can check the docs link: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html?highlight=group#module-telethon.tl.custom.dialog